# How to copy Names from a selected multiple objects and paste it (combined) into another using a script?

Tags: scripting, objects, add-on

in my work I must do a lot of copying from different multiple objects and combining those names, pasting into final objects name. I was wondering if that can be done with a script.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

This will combine the names of the selected objects and over write the name of an object called "Output" with the combined names of all the selected objects.
By default, the order of the names will be the order that the objects were created. This is the most simple case.

Paste this into the text editor, create an object called "Output", select some other objects and click the play button in the text editor.

```
import bpy

name = ""
context = bpy.context
data = bpy.data

for obj in context.view_layer.objects.selected:
    name = name + obj.name
    
data.objects['Output'].name = name
```